# Can not change the background image of a pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

I am trying to change the image in a picturebox when I hover the mouse over it. I am using visual c# 2010 express with windows forms.

Here is the basic code I have at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pbMV_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbMV.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.mvhov;
            tbname.Text = "Hello";

        }

        private void pbMV_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbname.Text = "";
        }



    }
}
```

In the following line it gives me an error in regard to the use of `My` .

```
pbMV.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.mvhov;
```

> The name 'My' does not exist in the current context

SO what am I doing wrong in trying to change the background image of the picture box when I hover my mouse over it?

Sorry if this seems basic too you I have next to no knowledge in c#.]
Thanks.

Comment: What does `My` refers to in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not have VB.Net's `My` keyword.

Instead, you can access the `Resources` class directly:

```
Properties.Resources.SomeResourceName
```